# A generic Intent to launch Calendar app on Android?

Tags: android, calendar, android-intent

For stock Android ROMs, we can launch the Google Calendar app by:

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);

intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");   

intent.putExtra("title", "Some title");

intent.putExtra("description", "Some description");

startActivity(intent);
```

However, it looks like manufacturers w/ custom UIs implemented their own Calendar, such as HTC Sense UI.
I'm not sure about MotoBlur and Samsung TouchWiz, but I assume they are doing the same.

So, the question is: is there a generic Intent we can use to launch the Calendar app on Android phones (regardless it's stock android or custom UI)? Or we kind of need to write a wrapper class to check and launch the appropriate calendars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no supported API for the calendar.  What you are doing is relying on private implementation details (the need to hand-write a string literal for the MIME type indicates this), so you are going to get different behavior on different devices depending their implementation.